# JavaScript bookmarklet in IE7

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to get my JavaScript working in IE7 which works smoothly in all other browsers.

```
document.write('<li><a class="bookmarklet" href="javascript:x=document;a=encodeURIComponent(x.location.href);t=encodeURIComponent(x.title);d=encodeURIComponent('+selection+');open(\'<?php echo createURL('bookmarks', $GLOBALS['user']); ?>?action=add&amp;popup=1&amp;address=\'+a+\'&amp;title=\'+t+\'&amp;description=\'+d,\'<?php echo jsEscTitle($GLOBALS['sitename']); ?>\',\'modal=1,status=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,width=790,height=465,left=\'+(screen.width-790)/2+\',top=\'+(screen.height-425)/2);void 0;"><?php echo jsEscTitle(sprintf(T_('Share with %s '), $GLOBALS['sitename'])); ?><\/a><\/li>');
```

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What errors do you get? Also, your code contains PHP, which is meaningless in the context. Please show the final, rendered code

Comment: Thanks Pekka. All I get is invalid argument which a very generic error.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<li><a class="bookmarklet" href="javascript:x=document;a=encodeURIComponent(x.location.href);t=encodeURIComponent(x.title);d=encodeURIComponent('+selection+');open(\'<?php echo createURL(\'bookmarks\', $GLOBALS[\'user\']); ?>?action=add&amp;popup=1&amp;address=\'+a+\'&amp;title=\'+t+\'&amp;description=\'+d,\'<?php echo jsEscTitle($GLOBALS[\'sitename\']); ?>\',\'modal=1,status=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,width=790,height=465,left=\'+(screen.width-790)/2+\',top=\'+(screen.height-425)/2);void 0;"><?php echo jsEscTitle(sprintf(T_(\'Share with %s \'), $GLOBALS[\'sitename\'])); ?><\/a><\/li>');
```

Comment: Thanks RamRam but that does not work and it gives me a HTTP 500 error which means those \ added to the code do not work!